# Missing a temporary folder error when uploading an image/media

Tags: wordpress

I'm facing a `Missing a temporary folder` error in PHO version (native, 7.2).

I have already tried the bellow method:

```
define(‘WP_TEMP_DIR’,dirname(_FILE_). ‘/wp-content/temp/’);
```

but it had no result. Can you give me some solutions?

Comment: assuming you mean PHP 7.2 rather then PHO 7.2

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in the config

```
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(_FILE_) . '/wp-content/temp/');
```

then create the temp folder manually on wp-content folder :).

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue, there are some [obvious solutions if you google about it](https://www.google.com/search?q=missing%20a%20temporary%20folder%20wordpress)...

In my situation that wasn't working. My setup was:

> PHP 7.4.28
> Ubuntu 20.4
> Apache 2.4.41
> WordPress 5.9.2

I came arround [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752396) and could finally resolve the error.

In short therms:
The apache2 / httpd systemd service uses `PrivateTmp=true`, its own version of the tmp dir. This is why wordpress couldn't find its "temporary folder" anymore.

I solved it by commenting out the respective entry in `apache2.service`:
(if you deeply care about security you might find another way to deal with it...)

```
[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Documentation=https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=APACHE_STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD=true
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
# PrivateTmp=true
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

don't forget to:

- reload deamon: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
- restart apache: `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

...